# Error in getting results from Excel file

Tags: excel, laravel-5.1, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to retrieve results from an Excel file to save in the database column. Here is what I am trying:

```
public function addRecords(Request $request){
        $file = $request->get('file');
        //echo $file;
        Excel::load($file, function($reader){
            $results = $reader->get()->toArray();

            echo $results;
            foreach($results as $key => $value){
                $sim = new Sim();
                $sim->msisdn = $value['msisdn'];
                $sim->imei = $value['imei'];
                $sim->issued_to = $value['issued_to'];
                $sim->associated_with_employee = $value['associated_with_employee'];

                $sim->save();
            }
        });
    }
```

I am getting error:

> Undefined index: msisdn|imei|issued_to|associated_with_employee.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of trying different solutions and reading again `http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#formatting` I found the error. The problem was I was not mentioning the sheet name. So, I fixed my error by adding

```
Excel::selectSheets('Sheet1')->load();
```

I hope it may help some future users.